# How to convert smiles (.smi) to pickle (.pkl)

Tags: python, pickle

I converted my `.smi` files to `.pkl` but I am getting this error when I load the picke file:

```
smi2pkl.py:16 in <module>
    qm9_smiles = pkl.load(f)

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '['.
```

I think the way I converted it is wrong hence the error. Any suggestions for me are welcome. Thank you in advance

Here is a snippet of code I used for the conversion:

```
with open(out_path, "wb") as f:
    pkl.dump(file_path, f, protocol=pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Here is a part of .smi file that I am loading:

C\F.C(=C([C][C]O[Zn@]12OCOZnO1)/F)([C][C]/C(=C([C])/F)/F)/F.c12C(=O)OZnOC(=O)c3ccc(CO[Zn])cc3.[C]/C(=C([C])/F)/F.[C]/C(=C([C])/F)/F.[C]/C(=C([C])/F)/F.[C]/C(=[C]/F)/F.C\F.C\F.C\F.C\F.C\F.C\F.C[O].C[O].[O]  str_m1_o1_o2_f0_pcu.sym.6
C(=[CH])([C])O[C]CC.COCCC.c12[C]3OZnOCO[Zn]OCO[Zn]O3.c12[C]3OZn@@(O[Zn]O3)OCO[Zn][O].[C]/C=[C]/O[C]CC.[C]/C=C([C])/O[C]CC.[C](/C=%5BC%5D/O%5BC%5DCC)[C].COC(=[CH])[C].C(=[CH])([C])OCCC.COC(=[CH])[C].CO[C]=[CH].COCCC.COCCC.[C]=O.C[O].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H].[H]   str_m1_o1_o2_f0_pcu.sym.5
C(=C[C][C]1O[Zn]O[C]2c3c(c(c([C]4OZnO[C][C]/C=C[C][C]/C=C[C])c(c3S([O])([O])O)S([O])([O])O)S([O])([O])[O])S([O])([O])O)[C].[CH]=[CH].[CH]=[CH].[CH]=[CH].[CH]=[CH].[CH]=[CH].[CH]=C[C].[CH]=[CH].[CH]=[CH].[H].[H].[H].[H].[O].[O]  str_m1_o1_o2_f0_pcu.sym.4

Comment: Can you post the first ten bytes of the file you're loading? I'm wondering if it's perhaps some other file format, and that's why pickle is complaining.

Comment: Hello @NickODell have posted some parts of the .smi file I am trying to load. Thank you

Comment: This doesn't look like a pickle file. You mentioned you created this file using `pkl.dump(file_path, f, protocol=pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`? Or is the file in some other format?